# Most Pythonic Way To Fill Pandas Column From Another Column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have a dataframe with 2 or more columns of numeric data.  e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'a':linspace(1,10,10), 'b':linspace(11,20,10), 'c':linspace(21,30,10)})

df['a'][3]=None
df['b'][3]=None
df['a'][2]=None

df
Out[98]: 
    a   b   c
0   1  11  21
1   2  12  22
2 NaN  13  23
3 NaN NaN  24
4   5  15  25
5   6  16  26
6   7  17  27
7   8  18  28
8   9  19  29
9  10  20  30
```

I want to fill NaN values in column a with values from column b if b is not NaN, or values from column c otherwise.

i.e. df becomes

```
df
Out[102]: 
    a   b   c
0   1  11  21
1   2  12  22
2  13  13  23
3  24 NaN  24
4   5  15  25
5   6  16  26
6   7  17  27
7   8  18  28
8   9  19  29
9  10  20  30
```

The most obvious way to do it is to loop through the rows and then loop through the columns, but what is a more pythonic way?

Comment: `df.a = df.a.fillna(df.b).fillna(df.c)`

Comment: or `df.a.fillna(df.b.fillna(df.c), inplace=True)`

Comment: Nice.  Thanks!  Is it more Pythonic to do df.a or df['a'] ?

Comment: i personally find `.col` notation cleaner, but this will not work if there is column the same name as a data-frame method (e.g. 'count')

Comment: dot notation won't work either if the column name is not a valid identifier

Answer (score 0):

If the number of columns is **variable**, we could use this:

```
reduce(lambda series, col: series.fillna(df[col]),
       df.columns[1:], df[df.columns[0]])
```

It successively fills the values in the first column with the second, then the third, and so on.

(This is based on @[behzad.nouri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625914/behzad-nouri)'s solution above.)