# Combine values from arbitrary number of columns into new one

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame that contains multiple columns with unique value in one of them for each row:

```
               A            B            C         D          E
0            NaN          NaN          NaN       NaN   POSITIVE  
1            NaN          NaN          NaN       NaN        NaN   
2            NaN          NaN          NaN       NaN   POSITIVE  
3            NaN          NaN          NaN       NaN   POSITIVE   
4       POSITIVE          NaN          NaN       NaN        NaN   
5            NaN          NaN          NaN       NaN   POSITIVE  
6            NaN          NaN          NaN       NaN   POSITIVE  
7       NEGATIVE          NaN          NaN       NaN        NaN
```

I need to combine these into one summary column:

```
0     POSITIVE
1          NaN
2     POSITIVE
3     POSITIVE
4     POSITIVE
5     POSITIVE
6     POSITIVE
7     NEGATIVE
```

I accomplished this using chained `combine_first` method:

```
df.A.combine_first(df.B).combine_first(df.С).combine_first(df.В).combine_first(df.E)
```

And later I found [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416886/most-pythonic-way-to-fill-pandas-column-from-another-column) using `fillna`:

```
df.A.fillna(df.B).fillna(df.С).fillna(df.В).fillna(df.E)
```

But I'm looking for generalization for arbitrary number of columns. I tried to apply these methods as reduction function, but couldn't make it work.

Any ideas on more elegant/efficient way to do this?

Comment: Will there always be only one 'POSITIVE'/'NEGATIVE' per row?

Comment: No, there may be more options, like 'UNDEFINED'

Comment: But I mean more than one non-NaN value per row?

Comment: No, it's said in the description that this value is unique for each row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my trick:

```
df.fillna('').sum(axis=1).replace('', np.nan)
```

Comment: Nice idea on summation! Thanks

Comment: @waitingkuo, What if I want to include a delimiter?